# Passing Element Through Sublime Text 3 Plugin

Tags: python, text, timeout, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am working on an Sublime Text 3 plugin and I have so far a little script which copy all text from current file to another using three classes :

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

# string and new file created
s = 0
newFile = 0

class CreateNewWindowCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        global s, newFile
        s = self.window.active_view().substr(sublime.Region(0, self.window.active_view().size()))
        newFile = self.window.new_file()

class CopyTextCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def printAChar(self,char,edit):
        self.view.insert(edit, 0, char)

    def run(self, edit):
        global s
        st = list(s)
        for i in st[::-1]:
            self.printAChar(i, edit)

class PrintCodeCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("create_new_window")
        newFile.run_command("copy_text")
```

the script is running via the PrintCodeCommand first.

I have multiple questions regarding this code :

1. Is this the 'right' method to do ? Because passing stuff with global variables seems a little dirty.
2. Is there a way to create a class that can use WindowCommand and TextCommand at the same time ?
3. the insert command (in CopyTextCommand) insert in the first place, is there a way to append at the end of the file ?

And another one : How can I use sublime.set_timeout() ? Because like this :

```
# ...
class CopyTextCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def printAChar(self,char,edit):
        sublime.set_timeout(self.view.insert(edit, 0, char) , 1000) 
        # I want to print a char one per second
```

Or using the time.sleep() command but it doesn't seem to work...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please avoid asking multiple questions per question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer in short here. If you would like more detail, please create separate questions.

1. No, you can pass arguments to the run command. The run method for CopyTextCommand would look something like `def run(self, edit, content)`.
2. No, but you can run a text command on the created view rather than passing it around. You can also apply a name or create an arbitrary setting for the purpose of identifying the correct view
3. Take a look at the documentation (https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html). The second argument is an offset.

Bonus:
`set_timeout` expects a call back function. For a one liner like you have, look up lambda in python.

Comment: 1. Ok,I will try that. 2. I don't quite understand your answer. 3. Ok, thanks. For the set timeout I'll try to test and understand how to do it right. Thanks !

Comment: Rather than having 3 separate commands, you can call `newView.run_command("copy_text")` from what is currently the new window command. If you really want to keep things separate, you can apply some setting to the new view using `view.settings().set("some special key", <some value>)` and search for that view. You may also name the buffer see `view#set_name` and search for that.

Comment: I need to do the copy by hand because I won't copy the entire file at once but instead I want to temporise it. The purpose of having multiple class is because I cannot create a new file, and manipulate the inside of the file at once... Or maybe using a built-in command of sublime like copy_text...

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your use case. You can access the content of the current view using `window#active_view`. From there you can copy whatever content you want. You can then get a new view object back as part of `window#new_file`. You store this in the `newView` variable. You can then run the insert command by using `newView.run_command("copy_text")`. Well, in the end, it's up to you.